# How can I display value of SUM(rows) using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using PHP to fetch all values from a column in MySQL database and echo the total number with all of them combined, with a WHERE clause. But I get no value displayed.

My database looks like this:

```
name|status|rows|
Mike|Klar|100|
Pete|Oklar|50|
Anna|OKlar|50|
Kirk|Klar|30|
```

My goal is to have "100" printed. (50+50)

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT SUM(rows) FROM registervard WHERE NOT status IS 'Klar'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Rows: " . $row["rows"]. " <br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

I expect "100", but the page is blank. If I remove the WHERE clause I get "0 results"

Comment: A blank page means something is wrong and is throwing a 500 Internal Server Error. Check your server error logs to find out why. I'm thinking it's because your WHERE is all wrong. Try `WHERE status != 'Klar'`

Comment: Sorry. I am seeing "Rows: " but no value next to it. Sorry for being stupid.

Comment: The result would be `$row['SUM(rows)']` because you're not aliasing the column. You can change it to `SELECT SUM(rows) as rows FROM` so that you can still use `$row['rows']`

Comment: That worked splendid! "as rows" did the trick! 
Changed the whole row to:
$sql = "SELECT SUM(rows) as rows FROM registervard WHERE status != 'Klar'";

Comment: You need to give it an alias, mysql is returning a column called SUM(rows).  If you bar dump your result you will see what I mean. You probably don't want to be in a while loop either as you only have one result unless you do some group by clause not written here,  you'd be better off using fetchColumn

Comment: @jameson2012 `->fetchColumn()` is for *PDO*. For *mysqli* you would use `->fetch_row()[0]`.

Comment: If you used error reporting you would see _Notice: Undefined index: rows_

Comment: @PaulSpiegel yes sorry fair point I hadn't looked at the connection just the query, though I was more suggesting the concept of only needing to fetch the single result than creating a loop :)

Answer (score 1):

There's two issues: Your where is clunky, and you're not getting the right column name when you fetch the array. If you change the query to this to fix the WHERE and use an alias for the SUM

```
SELECT SUM(`rows`) as 'rows' FROM registervard WHERE `status` != 'Klar'
```

You'll be able to get the result

Comment: Just a small note: `rows` is now a [reserved word in MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/reserved-words/), which many people use as an alternative to MySQL. Enclose it with backticks to use it as a name of a column.

Answer (score 0):

Let me help you fix your code and hopefully teach you few tricks.

- In MySQL you can only use the `IS` or `IS NOT` operator to compare against booleans, i.e. `TRUE`, `FALSE`, or `UNKNOWN`. - [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-not)
- To compare against a string value or any other value you can use the [not-equals operator `!=`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal)
- You should also enable MySQLi exceptions to see the error messages if there are any. Use `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before opening connection.
- Check against `num_rows` in your code is also wrong because `SELECT SUM(...) ...` will always give you 1 row even if there were no records matched.

Consider this fixed version of your code:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT SUM(`rows`) AS sumOfRows FROM registervard WHERE status != 'Klar'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
if (isset($row["sumOfRows"])) {
    echo "Rows: " . $row["sumOfRows"]. " <br>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

- First line enables exception mode. You do not need to check for connection errors manually anymore.
- In you query I changed `WHERE NOT status IS 'Klar'` to `WHERE status != 'Klar'`.
- If you ever decide to use MariaDB, then remember that `rows` is now a reserved keyword, so you have to enclose it with backticks like `` `rows` ``
- You could use `` $row["SUM(`rows`)"] ``, but if you use alias it will make your code simpler. Add alias to the sum like this `` SUM(`rows`) AS sumOfRows `` and then you can access it like `$row["sumOfRows"]`
- There is no need to loop on the results, because sum will always be returned as a single row unless you use aggregation.
- To check if there were any rows matched at all use `isset($row["sumOfRows"])`. This makes a distinction between a sum of 0 and no records matched.

Comment: "`SELECT SUM(...) ...` will always give you 1 row" - To be more more accurate: Queries with aggregate functions (like `SUM()` or `COUNT()`) **and without a GROUP BY clause** always return exactly one row.

Answer (score -1):

If you want use where status is not klar. Change your code to this...

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(rows) FROM registervard WHERE  status != 'Klar'";
```